# Add image to existing document

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfstamper

In my application I have to add barcode image to the existing PDF document. I can write the modified PDF with zero bytes. I am new to iText. I am not able to find issues in this code and I have no time to analyse make it working.

```
PdfReader reader = null ;
PdfStamper pdfStamper = null ;
PdfWriter writer = null ;

reader = new PdfReader("....\\barcode.pdf");
pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream();

Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
String barcodeValue = "" ;
code128.setCode(barcodeValue);
PdfContentByte contentByte = null ;

for(int i = 1 ; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages() ; i ++){
      contentByte = pdfStamper.getUnderContent(i);
      code128.setAltText("");
      code128.setBarHeight((float) (10));

      Image image = code128.createImageWithBarcode(contentByte, null, null);
      image.setAbsolutePosition(23f, 20f);
      image.setBackgroundColor(CMYKColor.WHITE);

      image.setWidthPercentage(75);
      contentByte.fill();
      contentByte.addImage(image);
      contentByte.fill();
}
PdfDocument pdfDocument = contentByte.getPdfDocument();
writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, new FileOutputStream());

reader.close();
pdfStamper.close();
writer.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed clear that you didn't have time to do any effort writing your code as it is riddled with errors. Even your question is wrong! You ask *"How can I add an image to an existing PDF?"* However, when reading your code, you actually want to add a barcode to every page of an existing PDF. You create a barcode *and you then convert it to an image.* Why don't you add the barcode as a Form XObject? Also, it is totally unclear why you use `contentByte.fill()`. Furthermore, you are adding the image at a hardcoded position. Is that wise?

I've written an example that adds a barcode to every page of a PDF with 16 pages: [StampBarcode](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/miscellaneous/bar-codes#1356-stampbarcode.java)

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
Rectangle pagesize;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(i);
    pagesize = reader.getPageSize(i);
    float x = pagesize.getLeft() + 10;
    float y = pagesize.getTop() - 50;       
    BarcodeEAN barcode = new BarcodeEAN();
    barcode.setCodeType(Barcode.EAN8);
    String s = String.valueOf(i);
    s = "00000000".substring(s.length()) + s; 
    barcode.setCode(s);
    PdfTemplate template =
            barcode.createTemplateWithBarcode(over, BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.BLACK);
    over.addTemplate(template, x, y);
}
stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

As you can see, I have used an EAN8 barcode that shows the page number (padded with zeros). I calculate the `x` and `y` value based on the page size of the page to which I'm adding the barcode. I don't create an `Image` object. Instead I use a `PdfTemplate` object.

This is the resulting PDF: [add_barcode.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/stamper/cmp_add_barcode.pdf)

As you can see, there's a barcode in the top-left corner of every page.

**Extra note:**

somebody had the nerve to downvote this answer. I don't understand why. The only reason I can think of is that my answer was too good in the sense that I explained how to add a barcode instead of an image. Allow me to explain how that is done. It's sufficient to replace the `addTemplate()` method with the `addImage()` method.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(i);
    pagesize = reader.getPageSize(i);
    float x = pagesize.getLeft() + 10;
    float y = pagesize.getTop() - 50;
    Image img = Image.getInstance("image" + i + ".jpg");
    img.setAbsolutePosition(x, y);
    over.addImage(img);
}
```